# For loop 15th day and last day of the current month php

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, if-statement

This is date, The idea of this, it will increment the date by 15th day of the month and end day of the month base on the charge_installment value.

this question is different from this section > [How to get every 15th and last day of the month in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603709/how-to-get-every-15th-and-last-day-of-the-month-in-php)

```
$date = '21-JAN-19';
$chrg_installment = 4;

for ($i=1; $i <= $chrg_installment ; $i++) { 
    echo $date;
}
```

output of this loop.

21-JAN-19
21-JAN-19
21-JAN-19
21-JAN-19

---

the correct output should be:

1. 31-JAN-19
2. 15-FEB-19
3. 28-FEB-19
4. 15-MAR-19

Comment: what are you using your $i loop for? I don't see any relation between your date and your loop

Comment: @Mukyuu That seems to be just the number of dates he wants to echo, following that pattern.

Comment: If that is the case, this would [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660501/simplest-way-to-increment-a-date-in-php)

Comment: @Mukyuu its just for example

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I know. i just post the logic or idea of the date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get every 15th and last day of the month in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603709/how-to-get-every-15th-and-last-day-of-the-month-in-php)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date

Comment: guys i've already tried those of your suggestions, but those post will not output same that was given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$y=1;
$num_term = 10;
//start date
$month_sched = date("2019-01-01");
while($y <= $num_term) {
    //15th
    $month_line_15 = strtotime($month_sched." +14 day");
    //last day of month
    $month_line_last = strtotime($month_sched." next month - 1 hour");
    echo $day = date("M-d", $month_line_15);
    echo $month_int = date("M-d", $month_line_last);
    $month_sched = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($month_sched." +1month"));
    $y++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the last day of the month you can use `t` as the format parameter supplied to the `date()` function. To find the 15th of the month generate the time using `mktime` and convert to a date with required output format.

```
/* Initial date and duration of processing */
$start = '2019-01-21';
$months = 4;

/* reduce start date to it's constituent parts */
$year = date('Y',strtotime($start));
$month = date('m',strtotime($start));
$day = date('d',strtotime($start));

/* store results */
$output=array();

for( $i=0; $i < $months; $i++ ){
    /* Get the 15th of the month */
    $output[]=date('Y-m-d', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month + $i, 15, $year ) );
    /* Get the last day of the calendar month */
    $output[]=date('Y-m-t', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month + $i, 1, $year ) );
}

/* use the results somehow... */
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($output,true));
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019-01-15
    [1] => 2019-01-31
    [2] => 2019-02-15
    [3] => 2019-02-28
    [4] => 2019-03-15
    [5] => 2019-03-31
    [6] => 2019-04-15
    [7] => 2019-04-30
)
```

If, as the comment below suggests, you would prefer that the dates begin with the month end rather than the 15th of the month simply change the order within the loop that calculated dates are added to the output array...

```
for( $i=0; $i < $months; $i++ ){
    /* Get the last day of the calendar month */
    $output[]=date('Y-m-t', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month + $i, 1, $year ) );

    /* Get the 15th of the month */
    $output[]=date('Y-m-d', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month + $i, 15, $year ) );
}
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019-01-31
    [1] => 2019-01-15
    [2] => 2019-02-28
    [3] => 2019-02-15
    [4] => 2019-03-31
    [5] => 2019-03-15
    [6] => 2019-04-30
    [7] => 2019-04-15
)
```

To output the results in the exact format of the example results

```
$format=(object)array(
    'last'  =>  't-M-y',
    '15th'  =>  'd-M-y'
);

for( $i=0; $i < $months; $i++ ){
    /* Get the last day of the calendar month */
    $output[]=date( $format->{'last'}, mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month + $i, 1, $year ) );
    /* Get the 15th of the month */
    $output[]=date( $format->{'15th'}, mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month + $i, 15, $year ) );
}
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 31-Jan-19
    [1] => 15-Jan-19
    [2] => 28-Feb-19
    [3] => 15-Feb-19
    [4] => 31-Mar-19
    [5] => 15-Mar-19
    [6] => 30-Apr-19
    [7] => 15-Apr-19
)
```

Comment: this could help, it much better its start the loop on 2019-01-31, 

this example: 2019-01-31, 2019-02-15, 2019-02-28, 2019-03-15

Comment: please explain what your comment means - you want to start with the `15th` ? Your example data above begins with the end of the month so ...

Comment: Base of number of loops. $months = 4;



Array
(
    [0] => 31-Jan-19
    [1] => 15-Feb-19
    [2] => 28-Feb-19
    [3] => 15-Mar-19
)

Answer (score 0):

```
   $chrg_installment = 3;
$result=array();
$new_Date="";
for ($i=1; $i <= $chrg_installment ; $i++) { 
    if($i==1){
        $date='21-JAN-19';
        $date=date("t-M-Y", strtotime($date));
        array_push($result, $date);
        $new_Date= date("d-M-Y", strtotime("+15 day", strtotime($date)));
        array_push($result, $new_Date);
    }
    else{
        $date=date("d-M-Y",strtotime('first day of this month'));
         $date=date("t-M-Y", strtotime($new_Date));
        array_push($result, $date);
        $new_Date= date("d-M-Y", strtotime("+15 day", strtotime($date)));
        array_push($result, $new_Date);
    }   


}
print_r($result);
```

**Result** : [image]

Comment: This might help but the output is greater than from charge installment value. if you declare 3 on the installment, the loop stop unto it.